# Не удается открыть файл включение: guardcfw.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

Я этот файл нигде не указывал, может в свойствах где-то спрятался? Я не могу его найти! Помогите!

```
//Mr. BooM.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "resource.h"
#pragma warning(default:4716)
#pragma warning(default:4005)
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#pragma warning(disable:1083)
//...

//Mr. BooM.vcxproj
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <ProjectGuid>{523af8c7-2d14-4f5c-bfdc-2d224def97da}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>MrBooM</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <EnableFuzzer>true</EnableFuzzer>
    <EnableASAN>true</EnableASAN>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>false</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>false</SuppressStartupBanner>
      <BufferSecurityCheck>false</BufferSecurityCheck>
      <StringPooling>true</StringPooling>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
      <CreateHotpatchableImage>true</CreateHotpatchableImage>
      <GuardEHContMetadata>false</GuardEHContMetadata>
      <GuardSignedReturns>false</GuardSignedReturns>
      <EnableParallelCodeGeneration>true</EnableParallelCodeGeneration>
      <DisableLanguageExtensions>false</DisableLanguageExtensions>
      <EnforceTypeConversionRules>true</EnforceTypeConversionRules>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>true</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <OpenMPSupport>true</OpenMPSupport>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp20</LanguageStandard>
      <LanguageStandard_C>stdc17</LanguageStandard_C>
      <EnableModules>true</EnableModules>
      <UseStandardPreprocessor>true</UseStandardPreprocessor>
      <FloatingPointExceptions>false</FloatingPointExceptions>
      <ControlFlowGuard>false</ControlFlowGuard>
      <IgnoreStandardIncludePath>false</IgnoreStandardIncludePath>
      <CompileAs>Default</CompileAs>
      <ErrorReporting>Send</ErrorReporting>
      <CompileAsWinRT>false</CompileAsWinRT>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <UseUnicodeForAssemblerListing>true</UseUnicodeForAssemblerListing>
      <AnalyzeExternalRuleset>AllRules.ruleset</AnalyzeExternalRuleset>
      <OmitFramePointers>true</OmitFramePointers>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalDependencies>advapi32.lib; kernel32.lib; user32.lib; $(CoreLibraryDependencies);%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="Mr. BooM.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="resource.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="Resource.rc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Вот ошибки:

```
Сборка начата…  
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Mr. BooM, Конфигурация: Release Win32 ------  
1>Оптимизирующий компилятор Microsoft (R) C/C++ версии 19.32.31329 для x86  
1>(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation).  Все права защищены.  
1>Экспериментальные функции предоставляются в качестве предварительной версии предложенных языковых функций,  
1>и мы будем рады получить от вас отзывы об ошибках и предложения по улучшению. Тем не менее  
1>обратите внимание, что эти экспериментальные функции являются нестандартными и предоставляются "как есть", без  
1>поддержки, а также могут быть изменены или удалены без уведомления. Сведения см. по адресу
1>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=691081.   
1>cl /c /Zi /W4 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl- /MP /fsanitize=address /fsanitize=fuzzer /O2 /Oi /Oy /GL /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Zc:preprocessor /GF /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS- /Gy /Qpar /fp:precise /fp:except- /hotpatch /guard:ehcont- /guard:signret- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Zc:rvalueCast /GR /openmp /std:c++20 /permissive- /experimental:module /stdIfcDir "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\ifc\x86" /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc143.pdb" /external:W4 /Gd /TP /analyze- /FC /errorReport:send "Mr. BooM.cpp"  
1>Mr. BooM.cpp  
1>D:\games\Mr. BooM\Mr. BooM.cpp : fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: guardcfw.h: No such file or directory,  
1>Сборка проекта "Mr. BooM.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.  
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, сбой: 1, в актуальном состоянии: 0, пропущено: 0==========
```

Answer (score 0):

Ресетнул все настройки: все заработало. Только почему ему мешал этот файл я не знаю. Может скажете пожалуйста?